# Fetchall returning only one column in Python?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a a code like this:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', db='galaxy', passwd='devil', host='localhost')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT username, password FROM galaxy_user')
names = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
passw = [password[1] for password in cursor.fetchall()]
db.close()
```

The problem is I can only access either names or passw from the following code. With this I can only get the username. I get empty list for passw. Now if I switch this like:

```
passw = [row[1] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
names = [password[1] for password in cursor.fetchall()
```

I get the value of passw but names is empty list. What's happening?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After each `cursor.execute` you can use `cursor.fetchall` only once. It "exhausts" the cursor, gets all its data and then it cannot be "read" again.

With the following code you read all data at the same time:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', db='galaxy', passwd='devil', host='localhost')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT username, password FROM galaxy_user')
names, passw = zip(*cursor.fetchall())
db.close()
```

Another possibility would be to store all data in a list and then read it as if it were a cursor:

```
records = cursor.fetchall()
names = [record[0] for record in records]
passw = [record[1] for record in records]
```

Or how about a dictionary (name -> password)?

```
user_pass = dict(cursor.fetchall())
```

or simply (as @JonClemens suggested):

```
user_pass = dict(cursor)
```

Comment: I think the key here is that `.fetchall()` seems a bit redundant as the cursor should be iterable... Either, `list(cursor)` or I like your `dict(cursor)` idea :)

Comment: @eumiro, I just tested using Python cx_Oracle:records = cursor.fetchall()
names = [record[0] for record in records]
passw = [record[1] for record in records]  and name is None. Thanks